# Passing div class to javascript function as argument

Tags: javascript, function, html, arguments

Sorry just a quick question. I am just starting to code in javascript and I was wondering if there was a way to do the following. I would like to pass the name of a div class as an argument to a javascript function. Is it possible to pass the name of the div as a string and then use that string as the div class within the javascript function or is there another way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course. Why do you have this doubt?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask about what you are trying to accomplish, instead of asking about the way that you think that is should be done...

Comment: Sure. So I am trying to write one function to do something to different dropdown lists on a page. Specifically, to do something only to the dropdown list someone has selected.

There are several of these dropdown lists on one page and these lists all have different names and I was looking for a way to act on one of them at a time by passing the name of the list (which is a div class) as an argument to a javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you're trying to do with the class, I will guess that you want to add it to some div.

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
var someFunc = function (classToAdd, id) {
    // do awesome stuff
    document.getElementById(id).className = classToAdd;
};

someFunc('someClass', 'myDiv');
```

Comment: This would raise an exception, since `class` is a reserved word.

Comment: @MaxArt thanks for pointing that out, updated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: when receiving a class name like you used in this code, it is best to use "klass" so anyone understands that you're dealing with a class name .

Comment: I'm not joking, it is indeed a misspellings used to get around a reserved word class. check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299289/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-klass-in-ruby