# What is klass in rails? And how is it different from class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I saw klass in one of the existing rails project. Why is it used? and how come it's different from class in rails?

Answer (score 8):

One is the name of a class and the other is just an undefined constant by default. And for the pair you're more likely to see, class and klass,

the former is a keyword for defining classes while the latter is just an identifier (like any other string of characters). It's used when you would like to write the word "class" but can't because it's a reserved keyword.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299289/what-is-the-difference-between-class-and-klass-in-ruby) hope it will help you.

Comment: In case OP is asking about the `klass` on ActiveRecord association reflection: `class` is the reflection class while `klass` is the model class. When we have model `User` with `has_many :posts`, `User.reflections[:posts].klass` returns the class `Post` while `User.reflections[:posts].class` returns `AssociationReflection` class.